# How to find and highlight a text even its tagged in some elements using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Developed a script for highlighting the text which is linked into the other html page.

```
 <p>Click <span class="f1"><a href="#myModal" data-reveal-id="myModal">here</a>/span></p>

    <div class="leftspread">
    <p class="table-caption"><span>CHAPTER 4: Vocabulary Checklist</span></p>
    <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" ><span style="float:right;"><a class="close-reveal-modal" style="font-size:1.5em;">&#215;</a></span> 
    <div class="voca-head tspace"><strong>CHAPTER 4: Vocabulary Checklist</strong></div>
    <div class="voca">&#x00A0;</div>
    <div class="voca"><a href="page012.xhtml#pg012">business process re-engineering (n)</a></div>
    <div class="voca"><a href="page012.xhtml#pg012">business process</a></div>
    <div class="voca"><a href="page016.xhtml#pg016">business-to-employee (B2E) (n)</a></div>
    <div class="voca"><a href="page033.xhtml#pg033">corporate social responsibility (n)</a></div>
    <div class="voca"><a href="page022.xhtml#pg022">discretion (n), discreet (adj), discretionary (adj)</a></div>
    </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).scrollTop(0);
});
radioBtn();
</script>
```

List of keyword (above coded in `leftspread`) will show as popup after click on the text `here`

[image]

In the **page012.xhtml**:

CSS:

`.highlight{
    background:yellow;
}`

html:

`<p><span class="glossary">business process re-engineering</span></span></p>`

`<p><span class="glossary">business process</span></span></p>`

**Script:**

```
    <script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //alert( window.location.href.split("#")[1] );
    var currentURLString = window.location.href.split("#")[1];
    //currentURLString = currentURLString

    //alert(currentURLString)

    if(currentURLString != undefined){
    $(".glossary").addClass('highlight');       
    }

    //alert(currentURLString);


    });
    </script>
```

This working fine at our end, but all the text has highlighted yellow wherever defined `<span class="glossary">` however click only one word.

[image]

But i have to find a specific word which one is clicked from an anchor tag.
and some text has coded like below.

`<span class="glossary">business pro</span><span class="ls30 lm42 glossary">cess re&#57394;eng</span></span>`

It (clicked text only) should be ignored whatever coded around the searching word & highlighted however its coded without any classes.

`<span class="ls1 lm41">ation of <span class="f1 s2">business pro</span><span class="ls30 lm42">cess re&#57394;eng</span></span><span class="ls31 lm43">ineering </span></span>`

Could any one please fix and resolve this?
it would be very helpful and appreciated.

Comment: I have some difficulties to understand your post. Could you re read it and try to correct/clarify it?

Comment: My Question is how to search & highlight the clicked text in other html page even is coded with any tags. actually, it's highlighting the text using the code, if the text coded with out any tags `<p><span>Highlight the text</span></p>`. But i need, it should be highlight the text however its tagged `<p><span class="a1">High</span><span class="a2">light</span> <span class="a3">th</span><span class="a4">e text</span></p>`

Comment: Can you add any image to describe what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using page number `#pg012` in fragment `<a href="page012.xhtml#pg012">`?

You can simply use the whole text which you want to highlight `#business process re-engineering (n)` in fragment on another page.

```
<a href="page012.html#business process re-engineering (n)">business process re-engineering (n)</a>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var currentURLString = window.location.href.split("#")[1];
  $("#page012:contains('" + currentURLString + "')").html(function (_, html) {
    var regex = new RegExp("/" + currentURLString + "/g");

    var re = new RegExp(RegExp.escape(currentURLString), "g");
    return html.replace(re, '<span class="highlight">' + currentURLString + '</span>')
  });

});

RegExp.escape = function (text) {
  return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
};
```

I have created a similar [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/VwUzjEXlCwut92FICoHw?p=preview). I hope this helps!!

Comment: thanks a lot for resolve and give a new solution to this. however, could not highlight the word, if texts has tagged with some elements and how to escape these elements. e.g: `<p><span class="glossary">business <span>pro</span>cess,<br>business <span class="f1 f2">pro</span>cess, <span class="f3 f4"><b>business pro</b></span><b>cess</b>. It is a long established fact that a reader </span></p>`